# Automatically submit a form

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to get a form to submit automatically, which feeds a username and password to another form.

If I remove the javascript and just have the form display on the screen, and manually click the Submit button, the result is I get automatically logged in on the resulting page. This is the result I want.

If I leave the javascript in place, it actually doesn't automatically log me in but it does pass across the username and password pre-filled on the resulting page, then I have to click Submit on the resulting page.

How can I make it automatically submit the form to work the same way as a user actually hitting the submit button? Also I understand that this may not be the most secure way to pass a username and password across, but this is for a special use case.

Note: MyForm is a php page, and I am submitting to an aspx page.

Here is code of what my form would look like:

```
<form id='myForm' method='post' action='https://blah.com/Login.aspx'>";
<p>Username: <input value='usernameHere' name='Username' type='text' id='Username' data-index='0' maxlength='255' placeholder='Username' class='loginUsername' />";
<p>Password: <input value='passwordHere' name='Password' type='password' id='Password' placeholder='Password' />";
<p><input type='submit' name='btnSignIn' value='Sign In' id='btnSignIn' />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: how do you suppose to collect username and password before submit the form?

Comment: Does the aspx page check if the submit button was clicked somehow? Does the name->value of the submit button get passed to the aspx page if you submit the form with js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect there are other issues at play, as using JS to submit the form should replicate a native browser submit. 
You can try simulating clicking the 'submit' button via JavaScript:

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('btnSignIn').click();
```

jQuery:

```
$('#btnSignIn').click();
```

Comment: This completely solved my problem. click() must behave differently than submit(). Click worked perfectly for what I need!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onload` method for **javascript**

```
function submitForm() { 
   // **NOTE** set form values first
   document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
}
window.onload = submitForm;
```

Or with jQuery if you want:

```
$(function(){
   submitForm();
});
```

or with tag attribute

he typical options is using the onload event:

```
<body onload="javascript:submitForm()">
     .
     .
```

Comment: This did not solve my problem. It works and passes the form values across, however it does not submit the form I am submitting to automatically. If I take out this javascript and just display the form, and click submit it does automatically submit the secondary form.

Comment: @user3513237 did you see any erorr ?

Answer (score 0):

As the problem is supposed "post a form through php" . It may be achived by using PHP€™s functions fsockopen() and fputs() to send properly formatted data to a remote server. Here is a sample of code :

```
<?php

//create array of data to be posted
$post_data['Username'] = 'XYZ';
$post_data['Password'] = '********';
$post_data['btnSignIn']="Sign In";

//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

//we also need to add a question mark at the beginning of the string
$post_string = '?' . $post_string;

//we are going to need the length of the data string
$data_length = strlen($post_string);

//let's open the connection
$connection = fsockopen('https://blah.com', 80); 

//sending the data
fputs($connection, "POST  /Login.aspx  HTTP/1.1\r\n"); 
fputs($connection, "Host:  https://blah.com \r\n"); 
fputs($connection, 
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"); 
fputs($connection, "Content-Length: $data_length\r\n"); 
fputs($connection, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"); 
fputs($connection, $post_string); 

//closing the connection
fclose($connection);

?>
```

The above codes do post your form now to get redirect to that page , use simply

```
header('location :https://blah.com/Login.aspx ');
```

Comment: totally overcomplicated for what the user is asking

Comment: @sudosoul , as i think , he needs a form to post data but automatically..hmm?