# Wordpress GravityForm autosubmit with a parameter

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

I have a requirement to auto-submit a `GravityForm` with a form parameter. So, as far as I know `GravityForms` has the ability for you to send a parameter through the URL and it'll automatically fill out a field for you. What I want to do is the ability to send another field called `autosubmit=true` in which if that is on there, it will automatically submit the form.

Comment: What have you tried? You have to show us some code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generic solution for any form: [Automatically submit a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32879625/automatically-submit-a-form)

And here is a Gravity Forms specific solution: https://www.gravityhelp.com/forums/topic/autosubmit-with-gravity-forms

The basic premise of both is that you use Javascript to trigger the form submission when the page loads. You would need to make yours conditional so that it checks the value of your pre-populated autosubmit field.

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
    // Update "1" to your form ID and "2" to your prepop field ID
    if( jQuery( '#input_1_2' ) == 1 ) {
        // Update "1" to your form ID
        jQuery( 'form#gform_1' ).trigger( 'submit' );
    } 
} );
</script>
```